# Convert Handle (Handle_Object_Attributes) To wstring

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert the `RootDirectory` in the code below, to a wstring. This code keeps throwing an xstring exception error, why?

```cpp
NTSTATUS __stdcall ZwOpenKey_Hook(OUT PHANDLE pKeyHandle, IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes)
{
    if (ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory != 0) {
        std::wstring myval = *(std::wstring*)ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory;
    }
}
```

The code compiles fine, but throws an exception error (code 0xC0000005 - Access Violation).

One step closer .... the code below still throws an exception error (access violation) on the first ExAllocatePoolWithTag;

**Definitions:**

```cpp
HMODULE hDll_NtosKrnl = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("NtosKrnl.lib"));
    typedef PVOID(__stdcall * ExAllocatePoolWithTagFunc)(__drv_strictTypeMatch(__drv_typeExpr)POOL_TYPE PoolType, SIZE_T NumberOfBytes, ULONG Tag);
    ExAllocatePoolWithTagFunc ExAllocatePoolWithTag = (ExAllocatePoolWithTagFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll_NtosKrnl, "ExAllocatePoolWithTag");
    typedef VOID(__stdcall * RtlCopyUnicodeStringFunc)(PUNICODE_STRING  DestinationString, PCUNICODE_STRING SourceString);
    RtlCopyUnicodeStringFunc RtlCopyUnicodeString = (RtlCopyUnicodeStringFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll_NtosKrnl, "RtlCopyUnicodeString");
    typedef VOID(__stdcall * RtlAppendUnicodeToStringFunc)(PUNICODE_STRING Destination, PCWSTR Source);
    RtlAppendUnicodeToStringFunc RtlAppendUnicodeToString = (RtlAppendUnicodeToStringFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll_NtosKrnl, "RtlAppendUnicodeToString"); 
    typedef VOID(__stdcall * RtlAppendUnicodeStringToStringFunc)(PUNICODE_STRING  Destination, PCUNICODE_STRING Source);
    RtlAppendUnicodeStringToStringFunc RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString = (RtlAppendUnicodeStringToStringFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll_NtosKrnl, "RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString");
```

**Code:**

```cpp
NTSTATUS __stdcall ZwOpenKey_Hook(OUT PHANDLE pKeyHandle, IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess, IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes)
{
    if (ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory != 0) {  // means that "Rootdirectory" & "ObjectName->Buffer" must be combined to form complete path
        UNICODE_STRING full_path;
        POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION nameInformation = NULL;
        HANDLE kRootDirectory;
        UNICODE_STRING kObjectName;
        full_path.Buffer = NULL;
        kObjectName.Buffer = NULL;
        kObjectName.Length = ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Length;
        kObjectName.MaximumLength = ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->MaximumLength;
<ERROR> kObjectName.Buffer = (PWSTR)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, kObjectName.MaximumLength, 'mmoP');
        RtlCopyUnicodeString(&kObjectName, ObjectAttributes->ObjectName);
        kRootDirectory = ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory;

        nameInformation = (POBJECT_NAME_INFORMATION)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, 1024, 'mmoP');
        if (nameInformation)
        {
            if (NT_SUCCESS(ZwQueryObject(kRootDirectory, ObjectNameInformation, nameInformation, 1024, NULL)))
            {
                full_path.MaximumLength = nameInformation->Name.Length + kObjectName.Length + 2 + sizeof(WCHAR);
                full_path.Buffer = (PWSTR)ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, full_path.MaximumLength, 'mmoP');
                RtlZeroMemory(full_path.Buffer, full_path.MaximumLength);
                RtlCopyUnicodeString(&full_path, &(nameInformation->Name));
                RtlAppendUnicodeToString(&full_path, L"\\");
                RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString(&full_path, &kObjectName);
            }
        }
    }
    return ZwOpenKey(pKeyHandle, DesiredAccess, ObjectAttributes);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I don't want to give up on this one just yet. I'm only trying to concatenate the `RootDirectory` with `ObjectName->Buffer`, why is this such a difficult task?

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: What makes you think that casting a `HANDLE` (which is what `ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory` is) to a pointer to a `wstring` is a valid thing to do?  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You're not trying to convert to a wstring; you're trying to convince the compiler that it already is one.

Comment: If `ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory` represents a registry key (as stated earlier but now deleted), I'm far from sure it can be done.  Not all registry keys _have_ names.

Comment: I found some sample code on the web that seems to suggest that using ```NtQueryObject``` should work (can't get it to work myself). I'm also leary of using this "undocumented" API call, I was hoping someone knew of an alternate approach. The comments that were deleted suggested extracting to Unicode then wrapping into a wstring. I'm not having any luck finding any way to make this work either. There must be a way since you have to concatenate the "RootDirectory" and the "ObjectName" in order to obtain the full path.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: I am trying to redirect the original registry key name on an intercepted ```ZwOpenKey``` API call. In order to determine what the original registry key's ```full path``` name is (when RootDirectory is not NULL), I need to concatenate ```ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory``` with the ```ObjectAttributes->ObjectName->Buffer```. How is this concatenation accomplished?

Comment: It's fine to use `NtQueryObject` - its not going to go away - but I'm not sure that it will do what you want.  I think you will have to compare `ObjectAttributes->RootDirectory` with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, etc and infer the root 'name' from that.

Comment: Agreed, ```NtQueryObject``` does the job. I just hope this call doesn't get zapped in future releases of Windows.  :)